# How to add common style in less and based on dynamic class add different styles

Tags: html, css, less

Below is the HTML signature where I have a common class and I want to apply the same color property to both the div elements. But based on the background class which is dynamically getting added, I want to add background colors to it. Although the given LESS style is working I was trying to refactor the code which is not working.

```
HTML:
<div class="common background-red"></div>
<div class="common background-warning"></div>

LESS: (which is working, please suggest if it can be refactored)
.background-red {
   color: blue;
   background-color: red;
}

.background-warning {
   color: blue;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

I tried the below code but it is not working

```
.common {
   color: blue
   .background-red {
     background-color: red;
   }
   .background-warning {
     background-color: yellow;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using the ampersand character to add a class to a class like below:

```
.common {
  color: blue
  &.background-red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  &.background-warning {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Additional information on this can be seen here:
https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/